# Resharper 8: how to prevent return key from splitting strings

Tags: split, resharper, enter

i couldn't fix this very annoying problem.

```
string test_var = "Greetings World and Hello";
```

When i put caret inside the string between quotes and hit enter, it becomes.

```
string test_var = "Greetings World"+"and Hello";
```

How can i stop this behavior from happening ?
I dont wany any crazy behavior when i hit enter, when i hit enter the rest of the line should go down like this.So that i can perform my own intended string operations.

```
string test_var = "Greetings World
and Hello";
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper is attempting to keep your code syntactically correct, which

```
string test_var = "Greetings World
and Hello";
```

isn't. If the string literal were a **verbatim** string literal to start with:

```
    string test_var = @"Greetings World and Hello";
```

then hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> within the string would do what you say you want:

```
        string test_var = @"Greetings Wo
rld and Hello";
```

If you really want hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in **non-verbatim** string literals to create a syntax error, I'm not sure there is an option switch for it (I can't see one). I note that on the [original feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-58944), it was suggested that Undo should just undo the " insertion of quotes and plus", but it doesn't appear that this is how it was implemented.

Comment: I couldn't see an option to turn it off either , thank you for you input , looks like I'll invest more into my own written text formatter, because of these "too smart" "cant turn off" features.

Comment: I use the VsVim plugin where Enter doesn't always mean "line break". ReSharper is great, but it would be nice to turn this feature off.

Comment: +1 with a Vim plugin here (Viemu).  This totally breaks in-file search when the found instance lands in the middle of a string literal.